# Using an iterator with an enhanced for loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iterator

Okay so in my project for class I'm looking through an ArrayList of my class "Sprite" with an enhanced for loop, and I occasionally need to delete the Sprite that I'm looking at. I'm told I can do this safely (i.e. not deleting the Sprite I'm currently looking at) with Iterators. I looked it up on Oracle's java documentation but I don't really understand it..

Here's my method:

```
public void forward() {
    for (Sprite s : sprites) {
        s.move();
        for(Sprite x : sprites){
            if(s!=x && s.overlaps(x)){                  
                if(s instanceof Razorback && x instanceof Opponent){
                    x.hit();
                }
                if(x instanceof Razorback && s instanceof Opponent){
                    s.hit();
                }
            }

        }
        if(s.shouldRemove())
            sprites.remove(s);

    }

}
```

if(s.shouldRemove()) is where I need to implement an iterator. If shouldRemove() return true, s needs to be removed from the ArrayList.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't, as you need to call the `Iterators` `remove` method

Comment: You need to older for loop for removing item safely. Outter for loop must start from maximum length like `for(int i = sprites.size(); i >= 0; i--)`. Otherwise, it could be a cause of `ConcurrentModificationException`. Inner loop is fine as is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to loop (and remove) using the iterator itself.

```
for (Sprite s : sprites) {
```

should be changed to,

```
Iterator<Sprite> it = sprites.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Sprite s = it.next();
```

And then your `if` condition will be,

```
if (s.shouldRemove())
    it.remove();
```

Comment: Okay thanks! Seems to be working perfectly, but how is s getting incremented? I see s=it.next, but isn't it.next the same every time? Or does it.hasNext automatically increment it or something?

Comment: @user3304654: `next` both moves the cursor to the next element and returns it. I was going to tell you to go look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) but I discovered it actually isn't 100 % clear!

Comment: you can also use a predicate since java 1.8: sprites.removeIf(Sprite::shouldRemove)

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @Codebender answer: to limit the scope of the iterator variable, you can use plain `for` loop:

```
for(Iterator<Sprite> it = sprites.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Sprite s = it.next();

    ...
    if (s.shouldRemove())
        it.remove();
}
```

This way the `it` variable is undefined after the loop.